# Question regarding Taylor expansion of $e^{\frac{1}{x}log(1+x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I was studying an example of the taylor expansion of $e^{\frac{1}{x}log(1+x)}$. The example goes like this:

> $e^{\frac{1}{x}log(1+x)}=e *e^{\frac{-x}{2}+o(x)}$ as $x\to 0$

> $=e(-x/2+o(x))$ as $x\to 0~~~~~~~(1)$

> $=e(1-x/2)+o(x)$ as $x\to 0~~~~~~~(2)$

My question is: How to go from $(1)$ to $(2)$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: $(1)$ is incorrect, while $(2)$ is correct, so there is no legitimate way of going from one to the other. To see why, remember that $e^x=1+x+o(x)$.

Comment: Thank you! Now, since  $e^\alpha= 1+\alpha +o(\alpha)$, setting $\alpha=-x/2+o(x)$ yields $(2)$, right?

Comment: There is a missing $1$ in front of the term $-x/2$ in (1).

Comment: Right? Yes............